# When complete in app purchase i want to fire the api which id can i send to backend Api, for the reference id from apple i want

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

When complete in app purchase i want to fire the api which id can i send to backend Api. for the reference id from apple i want.

```
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                switch trans.transactionState {

                case .purchased:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     **HERE I WANT WHICH ID CAN I SEND TO BACKEND API SERVER**
                    // The Consumable product (10 coins) has been purchased -> gain 10 extra coins!
                   if productID == COINS_PRODUCT_ID {

                        // Add 10 coins and save their total amount
                        coins += 10
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "coins")
                        coinsLabel.text = "COINS: \(coins)"

                        UIAlertView(title: "IAP Tutorial",
                        message: "You've successfully bought 10 extra coins!",
                        delegate: nil,
                        cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()



                    // The Non-Consumable product (Premium) has been purchased!
                    } else if productID == PREMIUM_PRODUCT_ID {

                        // Save your purchase locally (needed only for Non-Consumable IAP)
                        nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")

                        premiumLabel.text = "Premium version PURCHASED!"

                        UIAlertView(title: "IAP Tutorial",
                        message: "You've successfully unlocked the Premium version!",
                        delegate: nil,
                        cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
                    }

                    break

                case .failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break

                default: break
    }}}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the identifier? Is the `transactionIdentifier` sufficient?

Comment: i want to send customer id to backend  API

Comment: You don’t have access to the customer id/Apple ID.  If you have set up your own account system, you can use your own identifier.